# Weird Corrosion on Subaru intake manifold bolt

Tags: subaru, forester, corrosion, intake-manifold

So I pulled the intake manifold off my 04 Forester xt and one of the bolts on the driver side had this whitish battery acid looking color.  Does anybody know if this should tell me anything?

[image]

Comment: Definitely looks like some kind of liquid/water corrosion.  Why are are you removing the intake - was there a leak? Where in the intake manifold was the bolt - was it near a water passage?

Comment: Replace the bolt!

Comment: It would make sense if its coolant. I'm swapping the Turbo, but also inspecting and looking for things just like this.  I'm debating sending the fuel injectors to one of those refurb shops.

Answer (score 1):

It’s nothing to worry about probably the bolt near the crossover coolant in the intake.

Comment: Sounds about right